# What's the proper way/syntax to access Active Record nested objects through the frontend's fetch request?

Tags: javascript, ruby, activerecord, associations, fetch-api

I have a React frontend and a Ruby Sinatra backend. I have 4 models in the backend:  [here's my ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDNDH.png). Here's the important associations below in a nutshell:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  has_many :genres, through: :songs
  has_many :reviews, through: :songs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :genres, :songs
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs
  has_many :artists, through: :songs
  has_many :reviews, through: :songs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, :songs
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :genre

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :genre, :artist, :reviews
end
```

My issues right now are mostly syntax and how to access the nested (implied) objects within the the body of my fetch request, and also how to access it in the backend. For example, `song.artist.name` will lead to `artist.name` but I'm having a tricky time accessing `artist.name` through `songs`, even though they have an association which should allow song to access this info and publish it.

```
post "/songs" do
  # artist_id = Artist.find_by(name: params[:artistName]) || Artist.create(name: params[:artistName]),
  # genre_id = Genre.find_by(name: params[:genreName]) || Genre.create(name: params[:genreName]),
  # thisArtist = Artist.find_or_create_by(name: params[:artistName]),
  #              thisGenre = Genre.find_or_create_by(name: params[:genreName]),
  # this_artist = Artist.find_or_create_by(name: params[:artistName]),
  # this_genre = Genre.find_or_create_by(name: params[:genreName])
  song = Song.create(
    name: params[:name],
    year: params[:year],
    artist_attributes: [name: params[:artistName]],
    genre_attributes: [name: params[:genreName]],
  )
  song.to_json
end
```

On the frontend, I'm pulling user data from a form where they provide `song.name`, `artist.name`, `genre.name` and `song.year` --

```
function submitNewSong({songName, year, artistName, genreName}) {
fetch(`http://localhost:9292/songs`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: songName,
    year: year,
    artist: {
      name: artistName
    },
    genre: {
      name: genreName
    }
  }),
})
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

I know it's not right which is why I'm having problems POSTing the info cleanly. The closest I've got is the `songName` (via frontend) POSTing itself to song.name but none of the other names (for artist and genre) post. I'm just stuck at this point so any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use strong params in this case.

You could use in you fetch body:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  name: songName,
  year: year,
  artist_attributes: {
    name: artistName
  },
  genre_attributes: {
    name: genreName
  }
})
```

and in your controller:

```
song = Song.create(song_params).to_json

private

def song_params
  params.require(:song)permit(:name, :year, artist_attributes:
                              [:name], genre_attributes: [:name])
```

if you want to access directly from params, you should use `params['artist']['name']`

Comment: Thanks for the response @Steven! I just have a follow-up question; I only have one controller (ApplicationController) - when you say "in your controller", do you mean within that AppCont or elsewhere?

As this is a school project, I'm bound to Sinatra and 1 AppController -- can't use higher level Rails just yet. I've tried the (comment) below but still running into errors.

Comment: `post "/songs" do
    song = Song.create(
      name: params[:name],
      year: params[:year],
      artist_attributes: params[:artist][:name],
      genre_attributes: params[:genre][:name],
    )
    song.to_json
  end`

Only `name` and `year` (from `songName` and `year` in frontend) get assigned but the `artistName` and `genreName` don't, and cause a general bug within that HTTP request.

Comment: can you post the error it returns?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this one out. Not sure if it's the most optimal way (it probably isn't) but it does work effectively as far as I can tell. Here for posterity's sake.

```
 ## post a new song
      post "/songs" do
        artist = Artist.find_or_create_by(name: (params[:artist][:name]))
        genre = Genre.find_or_create_by(name: params[:genre][:name])
        artist.update(
          name: params[:artist][:name],
        )
        genre.update(
          name: params[:genre][:name],
        )
    song = Song.create(
      name: params[:name],
      year: params[:year],
      artist_id: artist.id,
      genre_id: genre.id,
    )
    song.to_json(include: [:artist, :genre, :reviews])
  end
```